# How do I releaze authorization function for android app?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to releaze function for authorization my android app. I know there are many similar questions, but I'm interesting exectly to get function witch return "success" or "failure".

```
override fun authorization(login: String, password: String): String {

   var result: String = "none"

   val call: Call<UserAuthorizationDataModelRetrofit> =
        dataBase.getWordApiRetrofit().userAuthorization(login, password)


    call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserAuthorizationDataModelRetrofit> {

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<UserAuthorizationDataModelRetrofit>?,
            response: Response<UserAuthorizationDataModelRetrofit>?
        ) {
            val dataModel = response?.body()
            result = dataModel?.result ?: "failure"
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserAuthorizationDataModelRetrofit>?, t: Throwable?) {
            result = "failure"
        }
    })

    return result
}
```

I'm expecting function return "success" or "failure" acording to response of http request. But http request is asynchronous and every time I get "none". Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `.enqueue` is asynchronous. You will always get a `"none"` because enqueue is always not finished when `authorization` returns.

You can do two things.

One is use enqueue and do all your work inside `onResponse`, open new `Activity` for the user, set your `View` or show a `Toast`, etc.

Another is use `.execute`. But you will have to call `authorization` in another `Thread` and do your work in there. Note that this is asynchronous and you should not do UI stuff here.